# Regular Expression to avoid matching starting tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

My intend is that I need to match `HTML` tags that has some `freemarker` square brackets tags inside the tag.

Examples:

```
<img src="[#if]logo.jpg[#else]logosmall.jpg[/#if]" />
```

or

```
<a href="[#if]logo.jpg[#else]logosmall.jpg[/#if]">See logo</a>
```

so far I have this regex `(<)([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[\s\S]+(\[\#[a-z][\s\S]*\])[\s\S]+([^>]+?\/>|>(.*?)(<\/\2>))` which you can test on the following link with a good example

http://regex101.com/r/iZ7qQ5

As you can see, it is "fairly" working, but it is matching some extra tags `html` and `body` in the beginning.

I want to negate the finding of any other opening tags before the freemarker tag with a negative lookahead (`(?![<][a-z][a-z0-9]*)`) but it didn't work.

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the `[\s\S]+` part. This part is equivalent to match *everything*, since `\S` means everything that is **not** `\s`... under this pattern, all tags can be captured, as well as free text, etc.

I'm not sure this regex is exactly what you need, but it should put you in the right direction:

```
(<)([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]+(\[\#[a-z][^\]]*\])[^>]+([^>]+?\/>|>(.*?)(<\/\2>))
```

Comment: The `.` metacharacter doesn't actually include `\n` in its possible matches, whereas `[\s\S]` does, so these two expressions are not strictly equivalent.

Comment: You think the regex is good that way? or it needs to be improved? in terms of functionality and understand-ability.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it needs to be improved - you need to test it further. It is definitely _not_ readable. You might want to read up on writing good regexs http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html, https://rionscode.wordpress.com/tag/writing-human-readable-regular-expressions/